# Issue with dataEdit library in R

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to use the library dataEdit. Below you can see one basic example.

```
edited_data<-data_edit(mtcars) 
  source("/Simulation.R")
```

So my idea is to make some edits in table `mtcars`, and second is to continue with script `Simulation`. I select these two lines and press Run.

So after the execution of the first line, I can successfully edit the table. But the **execution here will not continue to the second line** with the execution of the other script.

After execution, I receive a message  `Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6346.` So my thoughts are probably some problem in compatibility between this library which is more dedicated to Shiny than to basic R.

So can anybody help me solve this problem and execute these two lines together ?

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible. You could separate both steps: first run `edited_data<-data_edit(mtcars)` mainpulate the data and save to `.csv` with `write.csv`, then load with `read.csv` and then `source...`

Comment: I understand your logic and also my personal thoughts go in that direction. But in that case, why do I need to use this package? Probably Is better to change parameters directly in Excel instead to use this package and import directly inside in R.

Comment: I think the package has its value. I myself use it to make intermediate changes in data analysis within R in complex situations on the fly. So finally it is a matter of choice and workflow whether to use or not.